# How can I fix the textview?

Tags: android, textview, cardview

I have a problem on my preview XML, the `cardview` shows perfectly on the emulator but not on my phone.

I like the first `textview` to be on the right side and the second `textview` to be on the left side.

My phone is in Hebrew.

Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio]

But on my phone, I see it like that (Galaxy Note 5 Ultra):

[image: Galaxy Note 5 Ultra]

How can I fix that?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white">

        //airplane

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/airplanetitl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="Airplane:"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Airplanename"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="676"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share your XML code here.

Comment: In the Android Studio preview you can set the layout to right-to-left from one of the setting menus at the top of the panel to preview how it will look in RTL.

Comment: i add my xml file

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I trim the code

Comment: Someone can help me?